# Combination of chipsets

Tags: bluetooth, microcontroller, microchip

I have a question regarding the capability of the combination of different chips.

We have a PIC16F1824 microchip controller, is it possible to connect this with the bluetooth module from http://www.microchip.com/pagehandler/en-us/technology/bluetooth and read data from a chip, which is connected with this microchip controller?

Comment: Both chips have UART interfaces, so yes you can connect them.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, both the PIC and the bluetooth module have a UART interface. The only thing you need to be careful of is if they use the same supply voltage. If not, look through the data sheets to ensure that the I/O pins on both devices will tolerate the I/O voltage mismatch. The most common case is a 3.3V device with inputs that are not tolerant of 5V logic.